# what for need into anonymous function pass jquery object

Tags: javascript

*Case with bootstrap:*

Example code

```
function( $ ){

}( window.jQuery );
```

Comment: Sorry, but after reading this three times, I just can't figure out what you are saying or asking. You might have to rephrase your question. Perhaps if you supplied a relevant snippet of your code (in particular, at what point you call `console.log()`), it would make things clearer.

Comment: sorry for my bad English, but I try :)

Comment: It's not your fault. It must be tough being a non-English-speaking programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done so you can guarantee `$` is actually jQuery within that function. Sometimes libraries will attempt to use the same symbol and conflicts can occur (e.g. Prototype and jQuery can both use `$`). This is particularly important in code that is widely distributed and may be used in many environments and configurations, like bootstrap.

Using this idiom can also help prevent the introduction of unwanted variables into the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid collision with other library jQuery gets out of global scope and here

```
(function($){

  // Code here

})(jQuery);
```

a closure is being used and jQuery has been passed in to the inner function as an argument and it has been received with the droller sign `function($)` so we can use `$` inside our function.

**Reference:** [jquery plugin writing](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)